# Jquery / Ajax form submission won't forward POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that generates identical forms with different values (ie. lines of a database)

When one form is submitted, I want it to trigger an AJAX request that will update just that line of the database without reloading the page.

I have this AJAX script in my header:

```
function ajaxCall() {
      $.ajax({
        url:"database_quickupdate.php", 
        type: "POST", 
        success:function(result){
         alert(result);
       }
     });
```

And obviously all forms have `onsubmit="ajaxCall()"` attributes set

But when I try to return the `$_POST` array from `database_quickupdate.php`, it comes back empty (meaning no data is passed to the script)

I tried various versions of serializing the data, including this here:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'database_quickupdate.php',
           data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
```

but this didn't work either.

Of course I can assign unique ID-s to each of the forms, but then how can I tell ajaxCall in the header that I want the values from the form *that_has_just_been_submitted*?

It must be something very basic, still, I'm lost. I think I'm missing something on the jQuery side, but I'm not even sure about that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> onsubmit="ajaxCall()"

You're calling `ajaxCall()` by itself, so inside it `this` is the default object (`window` in a browser).

So then:

> ```
> $(this).serialize()
> ```

You are trying to serialize the `window` and not the form.

You need to pass the form.

---

Don't use `on...` attributes. They come with a host of issues.

Bind your event handlers with JavaScript instead.

```
 jQuery("form").on("submit", ajaxCall);
```

That will pass the form as the value of `this`.